# directive scope expressions updating all new elements

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive which is prepend html elements. They all have position expressions from when the user clicks to place them on the screen, but when each new one is added the position expressions are added to the new elements. I only want it to add to the new element and not the ones already in the DOM.

```
 .directive("addbuttons",
    function($compile, PositionService, $timeout){
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: true,
        link: function ($scope, $element, attrs) {
          $timeout(function () {
            var square = $element[0], posX = 0, posY = 0;
            ionic.onGesture('tap drag dragend', function (e) {
            e.gesture.srcEvent.preventDefault();
            e.gesture.preventDefault();
            switch (e.type) {
              case 'tap':
                posX = event.gesture.touches[0].pageY
                $scope.posX = posX;
              break;
          }
        }, $element[0]);
      });
      $element.bind("click", function(){
        angular.element(document.getElementById('tagContainer')).prepend($compile("<div class='square' style='left:{{posX}}px; top:{{posY}}px' data-ion-pinch></div>")($scope));
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: i don't get all your code but you can use *<div ng-click="aFunction()"></div>* instead of $element.bind... it is more angular way.

Comment: I am using ionic to determine the X & Y position of the tap on the screen and add this position to the element and also create a new element. So when the user clicks on anywhere else other than the element created a new one will be added to the screen with its own X & Y position, but this position is added to the old element